# TypeError npm run dev

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, npm-install

I've cloned a Laravel GitHub repo, it has Laratrust and Laravel breeze. I installed a composer and downloaded node.js and did `npm install` && `npm run dev` in the project's file cmd. However this error shows up:
[image]
This prevents me from viewing the Laravel project on my browser as the page says 'Server Error' because I need to successfully `npm run dev` first.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the message error, there is some problem with you laravel-vite-plugin/dist/index.js file. At line 108.
It´s trying to replace some values of the appUrl string. But it's your appUrl string is undefined.
Take a look on the library's github issues page, for the issue. Maybe there is something there to help you solve this.
But by the error it's it: appUrl is undefined at node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin/dist/index.js file, line 108.